# Pandas iterate through comma separated string and return lookup values joined together

Tags: python, pandas

| Name | Ids |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | '1','2' |
| Tom | '3','4' |

If my lookup value is "Bob, Tom"  I want to return each of the IDs values and joined by a comma so

[In]   Bob,Tom

[Out]  '1','2','3','4'

Comment: `','.join(df.loc[df['Name'].isin(input_names), ids])`?

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below

```py
data = {'Name': ['Bob', 'Tom','Jimmy'],
        'Ids': ["'1','2'", "'3','4'", "'5','6'"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
input_index = df['Name'].str.contains('Bob|Tom')

','.join(df[input_index].Ids) // '1','2','3','4'
```

Comment: if there is a space in the name so insted of Ids it is "Id Numbers" how would I fix the code for that?

Comment: Please show minimal case in your problem.

Comment: This does not account for cases where I may have Bob2 as an additional record when I only want results for Bob but @Quang Hoang 's reply solves my issue